# Need to build angular 5 app with webpack with different environment file

Tags: angular, webpack, angular5, webpack-4

Hello i have implemented webpack in my angular 5 app.Now it is running properly.
But i am not able to set environment for my build.
Previously before webpack implementation i was building my app from below command

```
ng build--aot --i18nFile=src/assets/locale/messages.ar.xlf --i18nFormat=xlf --locale=ar --environment=arabic
```

Now i want to know after webpack implementation what will be the command with same configuration set in above build command.

For now i have just one line written in my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = require('./config/webpack.prod.js');
```

and my webpack.prod.js code is below

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].scss'),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      htmlLoader: {
        minimize: false // workaround for ng2
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

currently to create webpack build i am using below command

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=prod webpack
```

***Build from this command referencing my environments.ts file and messages.xlf file
but i need to reference environments.arabic.ts file present in my environment  folder and messages.ar.xlf from my locale folder.***

Comment: it is an angular specific question since webpack does not handle i18n.

Comment: yes i know but is there any way to do this.